# AWS DynamoDB QueryResult conversion to Json

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jackson, amazon-dynamodb

A query result come in the form of list of 
`Map<String, AttributeValue>`,

To convert a single `Map<String, AttributeValue>` to a JSON 
the only way I have found is to iterate over each key in the map,
and build the JSON string.

```
final ObjectNode node = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();

for (final Entry<String, AttributeValue> entry : item.entrySet()) {
    node.put(entry.getKey(), getJsonNode(entry.getValue(), depth + 1));
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?  Is there a way to get a result from dynamoDB as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going on. AWS dynamoDB documentation needs to be updated . (e.g) 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Query

AWS DynamoDB java api offers 3 options for doing queries, 
QueryResult,  QuerySpec ,  and Scan.
There documentation does not clearly distinguish between  QueryResult / QuerySpec.
 They return different objects, and internally behave very differently. 
QueryResult returns a map, which cannot be 
effeciently converted to json. 
QuerySpec returns aws ITEMS,  which can be converted quickly to json strings
They state in there docs that Queries (in general) have a max 
data return size of 1MB per query, so if you need to fetch more, then you must make subsequent calls.  What I found is that this only applies to 
QueryResult query method, which contains a LastEvaluatedKey, which can 
used to figure out the next "page" to fetch if more data is available. 
However, QuerySpec method does not contain the LastEvaluatedKey,  which confused me ,  then I figured out that QuerySpec appears to internally paginate the data for you.  I was able to return 4Mb with a single call,